# Show a PMF is largest at a point

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The problem I am faced with is below:

Consider two independent and identically distributed discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$.  Assume that their common PMF, $p(x)$, is symmetric around zero for all $x$.  Show that the PMF of $X+Y$ is also symmetric around zero and is largest at zero.

I have shown that the PMF of $Z$ is symmetric around zero, but don't know what path to use to start to show that it is largest AT zero.  The hint says to use the "usual" Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I don't know how that applies.

Comment: What do you mean by "common PMF"? The joint PMF? If yes, $Y$ does not appear in it? If no, do you mean that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos The meaning is perfectly clear.

Comment: @Did Not to me, it isn't.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos: He states that they are i.i.d.

Comment: @StefanHansen I have seen more than once people using "common" to mean "joint". Also, people make typos: Consider the sentence "Assume that their joint PMF, $p(x,y)$, is symmetric around zero for all $x$". Now change "joint" to "common" and also make the typo and write $p(x)$ instead of $p(x,y)$... So, I prefer to ask for clarification than writing an answer that may prove to be irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, for every $z$,
$$P[X+Y=z]^2=\left(\sum_xp(x)p(z-x)\right)^2\leqslant\sum_xp(x)^2\cdot\sum_xp(z-x)^2=(*)
$$
where, by symmetry of $p$,
$$
(*)=\left(\sum_xp(x)^2\right)^2=\left(\sum_xp(x)p(-x)\right)^2=P[X+Y=0]^2$$